# cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in assignment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

UPDATE 16.4. 11:02

Hello Tom! I tried your code change you provided and it outputs interesting values.
I did some experimenting with changing the for-loop size and the number that multiplies `i` inside the `txString[]` and this is what I observed:

---

```
**CONDITIONS:**

char tamp[20];
char txString[32];


for (unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++){
  char tamp[20];
 dtostrf(coordArray[i], 7, 2, tamp); //convert one of your coordinates
  for (unsigned int j=0;j<5;j++) {txString[5*i+j] = tamp[j];} //concatenate it inside txString
}

**OUTPUT:**

10:32:06.052 -> Yaw: 
10:32:06.052 -> 311.44
10:32:06.052 -> ,  Pitch: 
10:32:06.052 -> -0.03
10:32:06.052 -> ,  Roll: 
10:32:06.052 -> 179.99
10:32:06.052 -> *****txString****
10:32:06.052 ->  311.  -0. 179.
10:32:06.052 -> ************


----------------------------

dtostrf(coordArray[i], 7, 2, tamp);

for (unsigned int j=0;j<6;j++) {txString[6*i+j] = tamp[j];

OUTPUT:

10:43:55.371 -> Yaw: 
10:43:55.371 -> 310.51
10:43:55.371 -> ,  Pitch: 
10:43:55.371 -> 0.38
10:43:55.371 -> ,  Roll: 
10:43:55.371 -> -179.64
10:43:55.371 -> *****txString****
10:43:55.371 ->  310.5   0.3-179.6ART HELMET  //Here it outputs name of the BLE device I gave it in upper part of code I didnt mention here BLEDevice::init("SMART HELMET");
10:43:55.371 -> ************

-----------------------------

dtostrf(coordArray[i], 6, 2, tamp);  //here I changed the string width and it outputted only Yaw data

for (unsigned int j=0;j<7;j++) {txString[7*i+j] = tamp[j];

OUTPUT:

10:49:58.993 -> Yaw: 
10:49:59.027 -> 311.95
10:49:59.027 -> ,  Pitch: 
10:49:59.027 -> 1.91
10:49:59.027 -> ,  Roll: 
10:49:59.027 -> -178.10
10:49:59.027 -> *****txString****
10:49:59.027 -> 311.95
10:49:59.027 -> ************


--------------------------------
dtostrf(coordArray[i], 16, 2, tamp);

10:58:43.547 -> Yaw: 
10:58:43.547 -> 314.31
10:58:43.547 -> ,  Pitch: 
10:58:43.547 -> -0.08
10:58:43.547 -> ,  Roll: 
10:58:43.547 -> 179.93
10:58:43.547 -> *****txString****
10:58:43.547 ->                       HELMET
10:58:43.547 -> ************
```

Answer (score 0):

returning a local array(declared inside the function) is going to cause you problems because it gets out of scope as soon as the function ends. To return a local array it has to be dynamically allocated so it can outlive the function

```
float* result (float x, float y, float z)
{
  float* coordArray=malloc(3*sizeof(float));

  coordArray[0] = x;
  coordArray[1] = y;
  coordArray[2] = z;
  return coordArray; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Can I ask you how will it look like when I want to call a function? I am sorry, I didn't mention what datatypes are my variables.
    

float txValue = 0;    

double roll, pitch, yaw;

Comment: in your main you'll be having a float array pointing to the returned array from your function eg : float *myarray=result(the_valueof_x,valueof_y,valueof_z)

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the other answer, as `coordArray` has been allocated in your function, it will get out of scope whenever your program exit this function, thus the values pointed by your pointer will no longer be correct.

If you need to call this function several times and want to avoid memory leaks from `malloc` you can declare `float coordArray[3]` as a global variable, update it in your function `result` which will then be a `void` function.

Something like

```
//global declaration
float coordArray[3]

/*
Setup and other code
*/

void result (float x, float y, float z)
{
  coordArray[0] = x;
  coordArray[1] = y;
  coordArray[2] = z;
}
```

This way you will avoid your error.

Note: global variables are usually considered as not clean in C/C++, however, for embedded systems with low memory requirements and where a memory leak will have big consequences very fast, it is usually advised **not to** use dynamic allocation.

Hope it helps!

** EDIT **

As your result is `void`, you should not assign its return value to something, it is returning nothing. Just calling `result(yaw, pitch, roll);` will update `coordArray`.

In order to convert this array to string you should do it sequentially as `dtostrf` expects a `double` and you have several of them:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<3;i++){
  char tamp[4];
  dtostrf(coordArray[i], 1, 3, tamp); //convert one of your coordinates
  for (unsigned int j=0;j<3;j++) txStringYaw[4*i+j] = tamp[j]; //concatenate it inside txStringYaw
}
```

I did not test that though, there might be a small syntax error.

Note: i do not know if I understood your problem well, but in my code `txStringYaw` will contain your three coordinates. You can adapt it easily in order to have only the Yaw if you want!

Comment: Thank you Tom for your advice, they were useful and functional so far.

But now i get this kind of error:

cannot convert 'double*' to 'double' for argument '1' to 'char* dtostrf(double, signed char, unsigned char, char*)'

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if it solved your problem!

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous edit, the correct syntax should be `char tamp[4];`

Comment: Thank you, it works! Data is being sent and the output terminal shows something, but the output data (format) is little off... Maybe it is because the data is being sent without any delimiter and are stuck together. Is there any way how to split them?

Comment: Please post an example of your output so that we can figure exactly what is going on. As a wild guess, I think you want to add a space between the data, maybe changing to `for (unsigned int j=0;j<4;j++) txStringYaw[i+j] = tamp[j];` will do it. You might need to adjust the size of `tamp` however…

Comment: The `width` parameter in `dtostr` is 3 and you are asking 1 digit after the dot. Thus you will have at maximum 2 digits before the comma. In order to print values as 360 this is not enough. Have you tried to print separated values?

Comment: I saw a small mistake in my code which explains your output: change for `for (unsigned int j=0;j<3;j++) txStringYaw[4*i+j] = tamp[j];`  I updated my answer. You can try to change to `j<4` or add a separating character between the three directions.

Comment: I think you are getting there, your first condition is pretty near to what you want right? To get the digits I think you should run the `for` loop for all the character, something like `for (unsigned int j=0;j<7;j++) {txString[7*i+j] = tamp[j];}`. I think you are done!

Comment: @BorisAllAboutAnyth Was it successful? If so you can close this question and post your working code in order to help other who might have the same problem. Cheers

Comment: Hello Tom, sorry for the late reply. I am still working on it. Yesterday I was a bit busy and I didn't have much time, but this weekend I will upload my results and hopefully close the question. Anyway, I would like to thank you for the guidance and patience you had with me, it was really nice of you!